# Gradle build: NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/util/Selector

Tags: java, gradle

I'm trying to run jar-file, builded by gradle with Bouncy Castle library dependencies.

```
jar {
     manifest {
               attributes'Implementation-Version': '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT',
                      'Main-Class': 'com.example.fileutil.FilePrepareApplication'
              }
 }

  dependencies {
        implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.58'
        implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.58'
  }
```

And receive error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/util/Selector
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.util.Selector
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
```

As I see, one of libs (bcprov-jdk15on) contains org/bouncycastle/util/Selector in its classPath, and other one (bcpkix-jdk15on) does not contains.

As I suppose, this is caused by the fact that not all dependencies has been involved to jar.
Trying to fix this, I update jar declaration with:

```
 jar {
      duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
      project.configurations.getByName("implementation").setCanBeResolved(true)
      manifest {
           attributes'Implementation-Version': '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT',
                   'Main-Class': 'com.example.fileutil.FilePrepareApplication'
      }

      from { configurations.implementation.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
  }
```

But, when I run this jar, the error is:

```
  Could not find or load main class com.example.fileutil.FilePrepareApplication
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.fileutil.FilePrepareApplication
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.example.fileutil.FilePrepareApplication'
    }
Then in your build. gradle add as below:
mainClassName = 'FilePrepareApplication'
Also, verify whether the jar was built with the main class and file name is correct.
Also check the path from where you are running it.
Pls try as above.

Comment: I tried this. But with the same result

Comment: "from { configurations.implementation.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }"    cause the problem with main class.  But, without it the problem with "org/bouncycastle/util/Selector" appears.   When I build and run app without Bouncy Castle dependencies, everything is ok